# Best method for embedding source code in OpenOffice.org presentations?

Tags: openoffice.org

When creating (Impress) presentations containing source code snippets, what is the best way of including these snippets in the presentation? If possible, I would like them to be rendered with a fixed-width font and appropriate syntax coloring.

An obvious answer would be to embed a screen captures from a code editor, but this causes problems when showing the presentation on projectors with varying screen resolutions. Maybe it's possible to create a vector graphics image that will scale properly, or even render the code with some macros to provide proper formatting and coloring instead? Do any tools for processing source code in this way exist?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Open Office works but I'd imagine it's capable of rendering HTML. If I wish to copy some source code to a blog post, I usually find a tool that allows me to copy the source code as HTML. I suspect this would also work for Open Office.

I think [this is what I use for Visual Studio](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/11/21/copy-source-as-html-copysourceashtml-for-visual-studio-2008-rtm.aspx).